# How to use SonarQube Maven plugins without running a(n explicit) server?

Tags: java, maven, sonarqube

I'm getting started with SonarQube usage for JSF page static analysis[1] in Maven. I'm only really interested in using it in Maven since I don't like the idea to introduce another build command.

After going through [Analyzing the source code](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+Source+Code) and [the specific Maven guide](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner+for+Maven) I gained the impression that the plugin can only be used after downloading, installing/unpacking and starting a SonarQube instance at `localhost` and specifying the connection information in the plugin declaration in the POM. The plugin configuration parameter confirm that.

While this workflow might have advantages it is painful to use on CI services and the necessity to start a service manually in order to be able to build seems not very user friedly (given the fact that other development tools like Selenium or Arquillian pull entire browser, driver and servers in the background without one single line of configuration). Am I missing something about a separate plugin or configuration which manages an embedded or otherwise temporary instance to perform the analysis with a single plugin declaration?

---

[1] I'm aware that there're other tools based on XML validation which could do the job, but setting up a much more powerful tools like SonarQube seems to be a more flexible approach which will probably pay off.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to install SonarQube on your build server, but it is necessary to execute analysis (results will be pushed to it). It means that you have a working server somewhere and next you have to set required parameters:

- `sonar.host.url` (`http://localhost:9000` is a default value)
- `sonar.login` and `sonar.password` (if your SonarQube server is secured)

See all [Analysis Parameters](https://docs.sonarqube.org/latest/analysis/analysis-parameters/).

Comment: I see, thank you. Since SonarQube has an ivory tower issue tracker I proposed to add capabilities to the plugin to handle everything with one plugin declaration in the POM at https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/hM5j3CEb0ec. I started using SonarQube, but I don't see the point why there's a function to make the Maven build fail if there's an error or bug (or warning depending on the configuration) - while I understand the use of the web interface and dealing with issues outside of the build.

Comment: The idea behind failing the build is to ensure that your code quality does not deteriorate.